# MSMQ - ReceiveCompleted - Process Messages async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, msmq

I am using the BeginnReceive method and ReceiveCompleted eventhandler to listen and process messages from a MSMQ.

I have put the BeginReceive method at the beginning of the ReceiveCompleted eventhandler.

It looks like it's working fine in my console application.
Right now, the messages are processed asynchronously.

Question: 
Is this safe regarding thread-safety?
All examples I saw put the BeginReceive call to the end of the completed eventhandler. So I ask myself are there any issues when putting it at the very beginning of the completed handler?

```
private void InitializeQueue()
{
    try
    {
        _mq = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(_queueServerName).Where(qu => qu.Path == _queueAddress).FirstOrDefault();
        _mq.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
        _mq.ReceiveCompleted += MessageReceiveCompleted;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Failed to initialize Queue!" + Environment.NewLine + " Error:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}


async void MessageReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _mq.BeginReceive();
    try
    {    
        await ProcessMessageAsync(e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Error occured during report fetching:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Multi Thread access in your code, to understand and gauge the impact

Comment: BeginReceive is used in asynchronous processing to raise the ReceiveCompleted event when a message is available in the queue. I am not that versatile when it comes to async matters.. so I better ask before I get into trouble..

Comment: If order matters I could put the BeginReceive at the end and call the ProcessMessageAsync using `Task.Run`...

Comment: Please understand `Async-Await` doesn't have threads, to cause any issue, if you schedule using `Task.Run`, then thread pool threads come in the picture, would need synchronize mechanism for shared object, especially for write operation. Nonetheless the IO / Remote operations are preferably done using `Async-Await`

Comment: Does that mean, that ONE thread is shared for all MessageReceiveCompleted handler, for example:

We have three MessageReceiveCompleted handler triggered by incoming messages. So the thread works on MessageReceiveCompleted1, then on MessageReceiveCompleted2, then on MessageReceiveCompleted3, goes back to MessageReceiveCompleted1 for execution, if not finished within a certain execution time, it continues with MessageReceiveCompleted2 and so on? Right?

Comment: What I do is calling a long running web service operation in each MessageReceiveCompleted  handler  --> `ProcessMessageAsync`.
this could result in not keeping up with the incoming work, as one thread does multiple jobs in parallel...
Then i would preferable go with Task.Run, but then I have to limit the thread count...

Comment: Your understanding isn't correct, `Async-Await` relies on hardware based concurrency mechanism IO completion ports. This doesn't have any software threads, but is still concurrent in background. Till the point you create 3 or more `Async` calls, `await` for all of them using `Task.WhenAll`, which returns composite `Task`, post the execution start, they will execute in concurrent mode. In your pasted code, I don't find any Multi threading issue, single object `mq`, registers for an event, post notification, it does `BeginReceive` synchronously, then await a web service call in Async mode

Comment: Also note Web service being a IO call, invoking via `Task.Run` will be of little use, as threads meant for Compute processing will just wait for IO call to return. In your complete code snippet, it is no where that I can see multiple threads, which can cause an issue like race condition or corruption

Answer (score 1):

Yes your approach with async/await will handle the threads safely.c# asynchronous approach with these keywords will take care.
Being more specific about my answer the event handler method messagereceived (the method name should end with async)calls and awaits on the async method, if there is any blocking work inside this method the thread it's suspends there and executes further until other work finishes and returns, like in this case the processmessage async might be blocking and there can be further execution of call but I don't see you leverage it since there is nothing you are doing after calling processmessageasync,so the thread will be executing this if you ask if it's thread safe yes but asynchronous approach is not fully leveraged

Comment: Can you explain what does this answer means, and how does it answer the OP's question

Comment: Please add some more detail to your answer. Saying "Yes your approach will work" is just a comment.

Comment: BeginRecieve listens asynchronously and everytime a new message arrives the completed handler is called. For example if 15 messages arrive in a row, they all get executed in a couple of seconds. The question is, will they all executed by one thread shared amongst the workload, it seems so..